# Help im a monero virgin & dont know how to find my coin

Tags: mymonero

Ok so a couple days ago now i was trying to buy some bubble gum with my sweet monero. I found out that in order to get the bubble gum i had to have BTC, SO i was gonna use the exchange in my my monero for android app & then the next thing i know is my $81 in monero is missing . Can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Which exchange did you use?
if it's only your monero coin missing then you can pull up the transaction hash on https://blockchair.com/monero on know which wallet holds it.
You should also revoke all connected websites in your wallet until you can clarify this to avoid any further loss.